# In a native debugger, what must be done in order to resolve ntdll/other API symbols manually?

Tags: debugging, x64dbg

I'm reversing a Windows binary using *x32Dbg* and I have the following instruction: `call ntdll.776C695A`.
What steps should I take in order to find out which function this is and/or what it does? The debugger seems to provide some symbols but not all.

Thank you.

Comment: Hey @the_endian, just a reminder -- if you find the answer below helpful, please accept it so the community will be able to focus on other unanswered questions and for users coming from search engines.

Comment: @Megabeets Holy cow I have no idea how I didn't see this earlier. I've accepted the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply execute `downloadsym ntdll` in the command field at the bottom of *x32dbg*.

As you can see in the [documentation](https://x64dbg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commands/analysis/symdownload.html):

> **Command: symdownload / downloadsym**
>   Attempt to download a symbol from a Symbol Store.
>
> *arguments*
>   [arg1] - Module name (with or without extension) to attept to download symbols for. When not specified, an attempt will be
>   done to download symbols for all loaded modules.
>
> [arg2]  - Symbol Store URL. When not specified, the default store will
>   be used.
>
> *result*
>   This command does not set any result variables.

This should retrieve the Debugging Symbols from the [Microsoft public symbol server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/microsoft-public-symbols) and update the assembly accordingly.